# web-scraping with rvest in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, web-scraping, rvest

I want to use [`rvest`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/) to scrape a webpage. It works fine, but doing it in parallel fails.

**Example**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

LINKS <- read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/") %>% 
    html_nodes(".question-hyperlink") %>% 
    html_attr(name = "href") %>%
  paste("https://stackoverflow.com", ., sep = "")


Get_values <- function(x){

  RES <- read_html(x) %>% 
    html_nodes(".label-key") %>% 
    html_text()
}
```

**works fine**

```
DATA <- lapply(LINKS[1:10], Get_values) #works fine
```

**returns NULL**

```
library(parallel)
DATA <- mclapply(LINKS[1:10], Get_values, mc.cores = 2) #returns NULL
```

Comment: Which site are you actually trying to scrape from? SO has an API so you're likely using it as an example vs show what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Sure. The site is hemnet.se. The code behaves the same on both sites though, so it should be irrelevant to the question?

Comment: Your `mclapply()` example works fine for me on R 3.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 with all packages being up-to-date.  What's your system / setup?

Comment: Oh it does? My ```sessionInfo``` returns R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

Comment: I have exact same problem using mclapply or parLapply, Have you find a solution ?

Comment: @Latrunculia I have the same problem. Did you fix?

Comment: @user1946989 I have same issue, did you fix?